# Retiring to Europe- need US phone number for Bank transactions. Bank only accepts 2 FA through SMS from a US number. Can not find a provider-NO VoIP

Tags: usa, banking

My question is about Banks, 2 factor authentication, US phone number, SMS

Comment: What's the question though? Most major American mobile phone providers have plans that allow some kind of international roaming.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173470/worldwide-phone-number/173511#173511

Comment: Moving to Europe permanently. Need US phone number via US provider in order to receive SMS from financial institutions (401K, IRA,...) for 2 FA.

Comment: Have you considered keeping a phone with a cheap US plan?